# Qual a função do operador "!" (exclamação)?

Tags: java, operadores

Nesse método:

```
public boolean aplicaDescontoDe(double porcentagem) {
    if(porcentagem > 0.3) {
        return false;
    } else {
        this.valor -= valor * porcentagem;
        return true;
    }
}
```

O que significa o operador `!` ali no código `if`:

```
if(!livro.aplicaDescontoDe(0.1)) {
    System.out.println("Desconto nao pode ser maior que 30%");
} else {
    System.out.println("Valor com desconto: " + livro.valor);
}
```

Comment: É uma negação, ou seja, está negando (ou invertendo o resultado) o resultado do método `aplicaDescontoDe`

Comment: Neste link da MSDN há uma explicacao completa, com exemplos: [Operador de negacao - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1k6w8551.aspx)

Comment: To tendo uma pequena impressão que essa pergunta é duplicada.

Comment: deusculpa não sabia.

Comment: @user38537 nao precisa pedir desculpa, mesmo se for duplicata é bom pro site. Mais chance de alguém achar as respostas, pq elas ficam linkadas. De repente alguém pesquisa na internet e acha a sua primeiro.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters ele não disse que não era para fechar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em Java, o operador `!` é um operador unário utilizado para inverter o valor de uma expressão booleana. Assim, se uma expressão booleana é avaliada para Verdadeiro, o operador `!`, se aplicado a ela, inverterá o valor para Falso.

No exemplo da pergunta, ela inverterá o valor retornado pela função `aplicaDescontoDe`. Se a função retornar Verdadeiro, então o operador `!` inverterá o valor para Falso.

Uma forma de ler o código da pergunta é: "Se **não** aplica o desconto de 0.1, então ...". (Particulamente é exatamente assim que leio esse tipo de código)

É o mesmo que fazer:

```
if (livro.aplicaDescontoDe(0.1) == false)...
```

Answer (score 2):

O operador `!` serve para negar.

Ou seja, se a linha: `livro.aplicaDescontoDe(0.1)`retornar `true`, ao preceder do operador `!` ele torna-se `falsa` e vice-versa.

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        boolean verdade = true;

        System.out.println(verdade); // imprime true
        System.out.println(!verdade); // imprime false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**`!`** É uma negação, ou seja, está negando (ou invertendo o resultado) do método `aplicaDescontoDe`